# Problem with SQLite3 in Javascript. Finding value using alias

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I am trying to write an Javascript app.

My database looks like this:

Table: `MyTable`

Columns: `value, alias`

5, a0

How can I use sqlite3 to get the value that is '5' using the alias that we know is 'a0'?

I tried:

```
var value = db.get('SELECT value FROM MyTable WHERE alias = ?', ["a0"])
```

and I got the result:

```
{}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided looks mostly correct. However, it seems like you might be missing some steps or there could be an issue elsewhere in your code. Let's break down the process step by step and make sure everything is in order.

Assuming you're using the `sqlite3` library in a Node.js environment, here's how you can correctly query your SQLite database to retrieve the value associated with the given alias:

1. **Import the sqlite3 library**:
   Make sure you have installed the `sqlite3` package using npm:

   ```
   npm install sqlite3
   ```

   Then, in your JavaScript file, include the necessary import statement:

   ```js
   const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
   ```
2. **Open the database**:
   Open a connection to your SQLite database:

   ```js
   const db = new sqlite3.Database('database/file.db');
   ```
3. **Perform the query**:
   Run the query to retrieve the value associated with the given alias:

   ```js
   const aliasToSearch = 'a0';

   db.get('SELECT value FROM MyTable WHERE alias = ?', [aliasToSearch], (error, row) => {
       if (error) {
           console.error(error.message);
           return;
       }

       if (row) {
           console.log('Value:', row.value);
       } else {
           console.log('No matching record found.');
       }
   });
   ```
4. **Close the database**:
   After executing your queries, make sure to close the database connection:

   ```js
   db.close();
   ```

Make sure you have replaced `'database/file.db'` with the actual path to your SQLite database file. Also, ensure that the table name, column names, and the alias values match your actual database structure.

If you still face issues after following these steps, please double-check your database structure and verify that the data in the database is as you expect it to be.